# Transfer learning on yolo using keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, object-detection, transfer-learning

I am working on a project that uses object detection. I have logo images that need to be detected in a video. I am doing this in keras. I followed [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/) blog to convert the yolo weights to a keras model.

Now I would like to train this keras model with my dataset (transfer learning). I got right dataset with xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax.

**My Approach:** remove the last layer and use the sigmoid function to define the classes. However, the above link says that this keras model predicts both boundary boxes and classes. I am not sure how to achieve these boundary boxes from the model itself.

Comment: Did you faced any issue like ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data) @Model.predict ()